The Enigmatic Orbs
You find yourself in a peculiar room with three orbs placed on pedestals. Each orb has a unique color: red, blue, and green. A mysterious inscription on the wall reads:
"Arrange the orbs in the correct order, The path to freedom shall then be yours. But beware, for two of the orbs are lies, Only one holds the truth that never dies."
You notice that each orb has a message etched onto its surface:

Red Orb: "The Blue Orb is truthful."

Blue Orb: "The Green Orb is deceitful."

Green Orb: "The Red Orb and the Blue Orb are deceitful."


To escape the room, you must determine which orb is telling the truth and place it on the central pedestal.  The other two orbs must be placed on the side pedestals in any order.
Which orb should you place on the central pedestal to gain your freedom?

it seems to me that rot13(gur vafpevcgvba vf jebat? gurer zhfg or bar gehgu-gryyvat beo, juvpu pnaabg or gur erq bar be gur terra bar orpnhfr gura gurer zhfg or gjb beof gryyvat gur gehgu. ohg vs gur oyhr bar vf gur bayl gehgushy bar, gura gur erq beo zhfg nyfb or gehgushy.)

@suchislife If the blue orb is truthful, then the red orb's statement is also truthful.

Ahh... corrected, I think? =)

You should place

 the Green Orb on the central pedestal.


 The Red Orb must be deceitful because we are told only one Orb is truthful.  Therefore the Blue Orb is deceitful.  As we are told one is truthful, it must be Green.  This is consistent as its statement is true.


Somewhat interestingly, this puzzle would still be solvable even if the Blue and Green orbs were both silent.
